# Uniqueness of function $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration

**Problem :**

let $f\colon[0, 1]\to (0,\infty)$ is continuous function and satisfies :

$$\int_0^1(f(x))^3dx=2,\quad \int_0^12x^2f(x)dx=1$$

Find $f(x)$ and prove/disprove that $f$ is unique or not.

---

**My Attempt:**

From AM-GM,

$$f(x)^3 + 8x^3+8x^3\ge 3(64x^6f(x)^3)^\frac{1}{3}=12x^2f(x)$$

and integrate both side

$$ \int_0^1 f(x)^3dx + 4 = 6 \ge 6\int_0^12x^2f(x)dx=6$$

Since equality holds, $f(x)^3=8x^3\quad\Rightarrow\quad f(x)=2x.$

---

1. Is this method valid?
2. Does this ensure the uniqueness of $f$?

Comment: You didn't prove anything...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Take $f_k(x)=kx$ and $g_m(x)=mx^2$ and try to find $k$ and $m$ postive s.t. $$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 f_k(x)^3\,\mathrm d x=\int_0^1 2x^2f_k(x)\,\mathrm d x$$ and $$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 g_m(x)^3\,\mathrm d x=\int_0^1 2x^2g_m(x)\,\mathrm d x.$$

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 g_m(x)^3\,\mathrm d x=\int_0^1 2x^2g_m(x)=1$?

Comment: I didn't mean that a priori, but obviously, to adapt my hint to your specific question, you will have to normalize the result ;-)